# How to add <script> js include to the closing </body> tag in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add a  js include to the bottom of a page in React?  Above the  tag.  Looking for really clear explanation, as I'm new to React.

Comment: Why? What is your usecase?

Comment: The same way you would do without react

Answer (score 2):

If it's an external script and you don't need to interact with the execution or events, you can simply add it before the `</body>` tag in your `index.html` template. This would basically be the same as you'd do it with any other HTML document.

If you need to add event hooks or handlers from inside your React app, you probably want to render it as a component, likely with lifecycle events implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) as a way of bootstrapping your project.  React apps need a root node to mount onto.  This resides in an HTML file.  When you use CRA, all this configuration is set up for you.

Then you can just add your script directly to the HTML file.

The index.html file resides in the public folder. Anything you add to that index.html file will be available when the app is running.  Just be sure not to remove the `<div id='root' />` tag.

This is a much simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks for the 'public.html' hint. This saved a lot of time.